# Grails validate xml document against xsd 1.1

Tags: validation, grails, xsd, saxon

I want to validate a xml document against xsd 1.1 in grails.

My code for validating:

```
def checkXmlAgainstXsd(InputStream xsd, InputStream xml) throws IOException, SAXException {
    def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
    def schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd))
    def validator = schema.newValidator()
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml))
}
```

How can I validate against xsd 1.1?

When I try this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="WaitForSoap">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:all>
       <xs:element name="Firstname" maxOccurs="3">
         <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:element>
       <xs:element name="Lastname" minOccurs="1">
         <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I get the error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; 
columnNumber: 9; cos-all-limited.2: The {max occurs} of an 
element in an 'all' model group must be 0 or 1
```

For some transformations I already use Saxon-HE 9.7.0-5

So what can I do make my application validate against XSD 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Saxon as the schema validation engine:

(A) First ensure that the schema processor you are loading is Saxon-EE, and that you have a license key installed.

(B) Then ensure that support for XSD 1.1 is enabled.

For (A) the simplest way to be sure of this is to instantiate Saxon-EE directly. I don't know Grails, so I can't give you the code, but you want to replace "SchemaFactory.newInstance(...)" by "new com.saxonica.ee.jaxp.SchemaFactoryImpl". Alternatively you can use the various JAXP mechanisms for selecting the factory class that you want to load.

For (B) you could:

(B1) pass the string "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1" as the identifier of the schema language you want, to the newInstance() method

(B2)  call `isSchemaLanguageSupported("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1")` on the factory (in the Saxon implementation, this first enables support for 1.1, then returns true)

(B3) call factory.setProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version", "1.1")